# Como traduzir para inglês «pedaço de mau caminho»?

Tags: expressões

Esta frase com origem no Brasil tem vindo a ser mais conhecida em Portugal desde a sua introdução numa telenovela há vários anos.

Encontrei algumas traduções para inglês, com as quais não concordo porque, na sua maioria, são traduções à letra que não demonstram o verdadeiro significado da expressão.

Em minha opinião a tradução mais correcta seria, "delightful sin" ou "delicious sin".

Concordam?
O que seria uma boa tradução para esta expressão?

Comment: Obrigado @JorgeB. o meu teclado não tem acentuação para Português.

Comment: Uma fotografia fala por mil palavras. Eu não traduziria com palavras mas mostraria esta [**foto**](http://hypecrib.com/2016/04/sexiest-women-on-instagram-april-2016/)   Além do mais, eu mudaria a expressão para "pedaço de bom caminho"

Comment: husoi: se explicasses o significado da expressão, talvez não-brasileiros te pudessem também ajudar. :)

Comment: *Jail bait*, talvez?

Comment: O equivalente em pt-pt seria pedaco de carne que se traduz diretamente para Peace of meat.

Comment: @BrunoCosta "*piece*". "*Peace of meat*" seria "paz de carne".

Comment: @OnoSendai "*jail bait*" só se aplica no caso de ser uma pessoa menor de idade.

Comment: @ANeves o significado em Portugues será algo do genero "Podre de boa.." ou "Boa como o milho" mas estas são expressões que penso cairam em desuso e não são tão "simpáticas" como "pdedaco de mau caminho".

Comment: @Centaurus, a frase original nao tem o sentido sexista da foto.

Comment: husol, tu sugeriste "delightful sin".  E isso não tem conotação erótica???  Além disso, "pedaço de mau caminho" refere-se exclusivamente a aparência e ao sex appeal, principalmente do sexo feminino.

Answer (score 3):

Como muitas expressões brasileiras, acredito não existir uma tradução perfeita. *Delightful sin* traz uma ideia muito similar, entretanto *delicious sin* nem tanto, visto que *delicious* está mais associado a "delicioso" enquanto *delightful* a "prazeroso".

Visto que o sentido literal da expressão "pedaço de mau caminho" é alguém que por ser tão atraente te tira do bom caminho, eu diria que um bom substituto seria *looker*, mas não traz (nem de longe) a mesma intensidade de beleza que "pedaço de mau caminho".

A princípio, para denotar intensidade de beleza, eu usaria as expressões mais comuns do Inglês como *pretty*, *hot* e *gorgeous*...

Answer (score 2):

Uma tradução maluca +/- ao pé da letra seria `piece of sin` ou talvez `piece of evil`. Agora coloque uma imagem representativa e qualquer não-nativo vai entender.